# import win32com.client error

Tags: python, pywin32

When I try to:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
```

in Python I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       from win32com.client import Dispatch   File "C:\Users\Lynn\Documents\2e
>   master\masterproef\python\lib\site-packages\win32com__init__.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import win32api, sys, os ImportError: No module named win32api

I already tried to copy the files `pythoncom27.dll` and `pythonwintypes27.dll` to `python\lib\site-packages\win32` and `python\lib\site-packages\win32com` but that didn't help.

I've installed `pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.‌exe` from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`

I've also already searched for duplicated files with no success either.

I've installed other packages (numpy, ...) before and they all worked perfectly.

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: are you on a 32-bit windows or 64?

Comment: You'll probably need to install http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/ yourself or use a distribution (such as ActiveState's) that includes it.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg : my windows is 64bit. But I use IDLE which is a python GUI that works with 32 bit (I think... At top the in the shell it sais: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem :-) After some more google-ing I finally found something that helped:

http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=17163&p=156600

When I ran the .exe file with " selecting fix compatibility problem" everything magically worked!

Comment: 404 not found. This is why SO has a policy of copying in the full answer, and not just linking to ephemeral web sites. If the page or site goes away, at least the information remains here.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

That will work in a virtualenv, or with tox, etc